# Styling ListView Control with compact Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, windows-ce

I am working on a WinCE 6.0 Project (Compact Framework 3.5). Now I am trying to change the style (scroll bar) of a `ListView` control. But I can´t draw my own style, because there is no `.OwnerDraw()` method. Is it possible to customize the style of a `ListView` with CF 3.5? (especially the scrollbar style and the selected item background color).

Answer (score 1):

This method removes scrollbar from inherited ListView:

```
const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
//No ScrollBar
const int LVS_NOSCROLL = 0x2000;
private bool noScrollBar = false;
    public bool NoScrollBar
    {
        get { return noScrollBar; }
        set
        {
            noScrollBar = value;
            int style = (int)NativeMethods.GetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_STYLE);
            if (noScrollBar)
            {
                NativeMethods.SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_STYLE, style | LVS_NOSCROLL);
            }
            else
            {
                NativeMethods.SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_STYLE, style & ~LVS_NOSCROLL);
            }
        }
    }
```

Maybe you can edit it for your needs.